# Google Drive API: Cannot update file labels on a read-only folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I have two users: admin@example.com ("Admin") and user@example.com ("User").

"Admin" owns a Google Drive folder (let's say the fileId of the folder is "F1234"). "User" is a member of a Google Group which has read-only ("Viewer") access to the folder.

In the Google Drive Web interface, "User" can open the folder F1234, and "User" can click on the "star" button to put the folder in the "Starred" list. So far, so good.

Now I want to write an application which sets the folder as starred. So, I log in as "User" and I go to the Google Drive API Explorer (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/patch) and I give the API explorer the OAuth token to execute requests on behalf of "User". I send a "patch" request to set the folder as "starred":

```
PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/F1234?fields=labels%2Fstarred&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
  "labels": {
    "starred": true
  }
}
```

But this request fails, with a "permission denied" type of error:

```
403 Forbidden

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "userAccess",
    "message": "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file F1234",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file F1234"
 }
}
```

I checked that this very same request works fine with a folder owned by "User", or with a folder not owned by User but where "User" has read-write access. So it really looks like the request fails because of the read-only permission, but this is not consistent with the behavior of the UI ("starring" a file is not a modification, so it should not require write access).

Am I missing something or is this a Google Drive API bug ?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been reproduced.
I will report this for you.
Sorry for inconvenience.